# Predicate with many conditions and one argument

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

I'm trying to query contacts realm db but I've one query string, do I need to repeat it over in the predicate or there's a better way?

```
let contactResults = realm.objects(ContactRealm.self).filter("is_Contact == true AND full_name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR phone_number_one CONTAINS[c] %@ OR phone_number_two CONTAINS[c] %@ OR phone_number_three CONTAINS[c] %@ OR email_address_one CONTAINS[c] %@ OR email_address_two CONTAINS[c] %@", query, query, query, query, query, query).sorted(byKeyPath: "full_name", ascending: true)
```

also is querying like this considered a bad practice?

update: as suggested by a comment here:

```
let predicateContact = NSPredicate(format: "is_Contact == true")

let fullname = NSPredicate(format: "full_name CONTAINS[c] %@", query)

let phoneNumber = NSPredicate(format: "phone_number_one CONTAINS[c] %@", query)

let phonenumbertwo = NSPredicate(format: "phone_number_one CONTAINS[c] %@", query)

let email = NSPredicate(format: "phone_number_one CONTAINS[c] %@", query)

let secondEmail = NSPredicate(format: "phone_number_one CONTAINS[c] %@", query)

let compoundOr = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [fullname, phoneNumber, phonenumbertwo, email, secondEmail])

let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicateContact, compoundOr])

let contactResults = realm.objects(ContactRealm.self).filter(compound).sorted(byKeyPath: "full_name", ascending: true)
```

Comment: When filtering data like this it is very easy to get lost on the Predicates and as a consequence debugging is really hard. I definitely advise you to use [`NSCompoundPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/) for combining every individual Predicate. Also avoid any query like `is_Contact == true` instead do `NSPredicate(format: "is_Contact == %@", true)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your predicates look the same and only show a difference in the name of the attribute, I would suggest to create an array of attribute names. Then, you can create an `NSPredicate` for each name by looping through the names.

```
let attributes = ["full_name", "phone_number_one", "phone_number_two", "phone_number_three", "email_address_one", "email_address_two"]
let contactPredicateArray = parameters.map {
    NSPredicate("\($0) CONTAINS[c] %@", query)
}
let contactPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: contactPredicateArray)
let isContactPredicte = NSPredicate(format: "is_Contact == %@", true)
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [isContactPredicte, contactPredicate])
```

This way, the code is more flexible because removing or adding single attributes to your predicate can be done very easily by modifying the `attributes` array. It is also more readable because all attributes are defined in one line and not all over the place.